# domain doesn't work with www but works without www

Tags: apache, redirect, hosting, cpanel

I have setup a domain in cpanel hosting in AWS centos instance
I can browse my website without www prefix but when I put www in browser it goes to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

The cname record is already created for www and I have checked that ip address for this cname is showing in DNS tool.

I have tried by clearing the browser cache but no luck.

If I try using postman (without any browser) then it returns following html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

that means when I try from browser primarily it goes to a page where this html is present, later it redirects to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi page

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to fix it.

===edit===

my current htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^backend/(.*)$ /backend/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^testbackend/(.*)$ /testbackend/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

i also tried by adding following lines in htaccess but no luck:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

even i tried by removing the htaccess file. even a static file like http://wwww.mydomain.com/test.txt is not working

it seems if i request with www, the request not reaching to application

is this information help to identify the issue?

Comment: Such a redirection is (most likely) not done by the http server itself, but by some application logic processing your request.

Answer (score 0):

check your `.htaccess` file in `public_html` and append code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How should this help? It is unlikely that requests to _other_ domains are served by that http host and the issue is not redirecting to the "www host" of the domain name...