# www.domain doesn't work but https with domain does

Tags: dns, domain-name, ghost-blog

https://hapothesis.com works, but [www.hapothesis.com](http://www.hapothesis.com) doesn't work.

The site is built on Ghost CMS. I guess I could just add an .htaccess file like explained on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903237/domain-doesnt-work-with-www-but-works-without-www)?

Below are the settings on my registrar and host;

The registrar is Google Domains;
[image: Settings]

The host is Digital Ocean;
[image]

Comment: For me both sites work. Please provide the text of error message that you get.

Comment: You should redirect your domain.

Comment: @LovekeshKumar, looks like you're right, I need to add a server block as explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) However,  I'm stuck following instructions on how to do so [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04), any ideas on adding a server block? Server directory looks like this: "/ect/nginx/sites-available/hapothesis.com-ssl.conf", is that the file I should edit via nano?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, looks like it's "can't establish a connection." The Ghost CMS auto setup for SSL on self hosted installs doesn't include www, just on the naked domain.

Comment: So this is not a DNS problem. Both hosts hapothesis.com and www.hapothesis.com resolve to IP address 164.90.131.105. Redirection also works correctly. Problem is that you have Letsencrypt certificate for hapothesis.com only. You probably should install a wildcard certificate.